# Show/hide function evaluation in manipulate

Tags: manipulate, conditional

I am using Manipulate to plot a function, but I would also like the option of showing information about that function in the Manipulate control area, as text. I keep getting an error (see code / image below). The "Show b" textbox would switch the neighboring text on/off.  I just can't get Mathematica to "see" the variable `show` variable or access the function `f[x,b]` in this `If` command in the Manipulate control area. The `If` statement does not seem to be recognized correctly, either. Suggestions would be most helpful!

Here is a MWE:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, b], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 {{b, 0.1}, 0, 2}, 
 Row[{Control[{{show, True, "Show b"}, {True, False}}], 
   If[show, "b = " <> ToString[f[0, b]], ""]}, Spacer[20]]]
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

You're only missing a `Dynamic` wrapped around your `If`:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, b], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 {{b, 0.1}, 0, 2}, 
 Row[{Control[{{show, True, "Show b"}, {True, False}}], 
   If[show, "b = " <> ToString[f[0, b]], ""]}, Spacer[20]]]
```

[image]

The reason is that `Manipulate` doesn't really process or wrap custom controls too much, so you manually need to add stuff like `Dynamic`.

As for how to see what the problem might be: As you've noted, the `If` statement wasn't properly evaluated. In particular, you can see that the condition variable is `` FE`show$... ``, which indicates that it is a localized variable of a `DynamyicModule` (which is internally used by `Manipulate`). The fact that you see it without a value substituted indicates that the expression was evaluated in the wrong context, i.e. not as part of a dynamic evaluation (only those are properly scoped to enclosing `DynamicModule` constructs)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[
 
 Plot[f[x, b], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   If[show == True, Panel[Row[{"b = ", b}], ImageSize -> {70, 40}]]],
 
 Control[{{b, 0.1}, 0, 2}], 
 Control[{{show, True, "Show b"}, {True, False}}],
 ControlType -> {Slider, Checkbox}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

**Edit**:
To address your question. I do not know how to do it dynamically in the form of the label of the Manipulate panel (as you asked). However, please find below the way of how to show it in the form of the slider label:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, b], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Control[{{b, 0.1, 
    Dynamic[Panel[If[show == True, Row[{"b=", b}], "b"], 
      ImageSize -> {80, 40}]]}, 0, 2}], 
 Control[{{show, True, "Show b"}, {True, False}}], 
 ControlType -> {Slider, Checkbox}]
```

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Alexei: any way to get the text, "b = 1.538", to appear directly in the Manipulate control space, rather than in the plot itself? Thanks

Comment: Please see the edit.